# Create a div with iframe in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, overlay, fullpage.js

When someone clicks an image it will darken the screen and the video will play. But it's not working, any help would be appreciated. Thank you. (I'm using bootstrap and fullpage.js)

```
 HTML:
     <html>
     <body>
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-lg-3">
           <img "myImg" scr="images/myimage.jpeg"     myVideo="https://youtube.com/embed/" width="100%">
         </div>
       </div>
       </body>
      </head>

    Jquery:
       $("#myImg").click(function(){
     video = '<iframe src="'+ $(this).attr('myVideo') +'" width="600px"      height="auto"></iframe>';
        div = document.createElement('div');
        div.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.9)";
        div.style.position = "absolute";
        div.style.width = "100vw";
        div.style.height = "100vh";
         div.style.left = "0";
         div.style.top = "0";
         div.style.verticalAlign = "middle";
         div.html = video;
         document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(div);
        });
```

Comment: Can you please format your code - it's very hard to read how it is there. http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few errors:

1) Your jQuery `click` event is looking for a click on an element with the ID of `myImage`, but your image has no ID right now. Change `<img "myImg" ...` to `<img id="myImage" ...` to fix the click event.

2) You misspelled `src` (source) as `scr` on your `<img>`.

3) HTML is set on elements using JS with `.innerHTML`, not `.html`. Change `div.html = video;` to `div.innerHTML = video;`.

Changing those will get your code to execute. Preview of it working:

```js
$("#myImage").click(function() {
  video = '<iframe src="' + $(this).attr('myVideo') + '" width="600px"      height="auto"></iframe>';
  div = document.createElement('div');
  div.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.9)";
  div.style.position = "absolute";
  div.style.width = "100vw";
  div.style.height = "100vh";
  div.style.left = "0";
  div.style.top = "0";
  div.style.verticalAlign = "middle";
  div.innerHTML = video;
  document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(div);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3">
      <img id="myImage" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" myVideo="https://youtube.com/embed/" width="100%">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```